# Select maximum value from one column by second column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
EMPLOYEES
=====================================================
ID    NAME    SUPERVISOR    LOCATION    SALARY
-----------------------------------------------------
34       John                  AL          100000
17       Mike    34            NY          75000
5        Alan    34            LE          25000
10       Dave    5             NY          20000

BONUS
========================================
ID        Bonus
----------------------------------------
17        5000
34        5000
10        2000
```

I have to write query which return a list of the highest paid employee in each location with their names, salary and salary+bonus. Ranking should be based on salary plus bonus. So I wrote this query:

```
select em.name as name, em.salary as salary, bo.bonus as bonus, max(em.salary+bo.bonus) as total
from employees as em
join bonus as bo on em.empid = bo.empid 
group by em.location
```

But I'm getting wrong names and query don't return one employee without bonus (empid = 5 in employees table) which have highest salary based by location (25000 + 0 bonus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do

```
select 
  em.location, 
  em.name as name, 
  em.salary as salary, 
  IFNULL(bo.bonus,0)) as bonus, 
  max(em.salary+IFNULL(bo.bonus,0)) as total
from employees as em
left join bonus as bo on em.empid = bo.empid 
group by em.location;
```

This query however relies on a group by behavior that is specific to MySQL and would fail in most other databases (and also in later versions of MySQL if the setting `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled).

I would suggest a query like below instead:

```
select 
  em.location, 
  em.name as name, 
  em.salary as salary, 
  IFNULL(bo.bonus,0)) as bonus, 
  highest.total
from employees as em 
left join bonus as bo on em.empid = bo.empid 
join (
    select 
      em.location, 
      max(em.salary+IFNULL(bo.bonus,0)) as total
    from employees as em 
    left join bonus as bo on em.empid = bo.empid 
    group by em.location
) highest on em.LOCATION = highest.LOCATION and em.salary+IFNULL(bo.bonus,0) = highest.total;
```

Here you determine the highest salary+bonus for each location and use that result as a derived table in a join to filter out the employee with highest total for each location.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/631378/1)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using a `left join`:

```
select em.name as name, em.salary as salary, bo.bonus as bonus, max(em.salary+bo.bonus) as total
from employees as em
left join bonus as bo on em.empid = bo.empid 
group by em.location
```

Comment: Yes, this is working, but for employee without bonus, for total I'm getting (null) not just salary

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
select 
   em.name as name, 
   em.salary as salary, 
   COALESCE(bo.bonus,0) as bonus, 
   max(em.salary + COALESCE(bo.bonus,0) ) as total
from employees as em
left join bonus as bo on em.empid = bo.empid 
group by em.location
```

You can check it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a064ce/2)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 select em.name as name, em.salary as salary,ISNULL(bo.bonus,0) as bonus,
     max(em.salary+ISNULL(bo.bonus,0)) as total
    from employees as em
    left join bonus as bo on em.ID = bo.ID 
    group by  em.name,em.salary, bo.bonus order by MAX(em.salary+ISNULL(bo.bonus,0)) Desc
```

Comment: `ISNULL` takes one parameter. It should be rather `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` instead